# When the L2 page is copied to L1 page?

Tags: caching, operating-system, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I'm not sure I understand correctly the idea behinds of L1 and `L2` cache.

When we use the `read` command, the logic behinds:

- first check if the data is stored in the `L1` cache  (which is faster) and if not, it checks the `L2` cache.

  1. So if the data stored in `L2` cache, does the OS copy this page to `L1` cache immediately ?
  2. Now, if we want to `write` data, it is immediately write to `L1` or `L2` cache ?

Comment: CPU caches operate in chunks called "lines" (e.g. 64 bytes on most modern CPUs).  virtual-memory pages are much larger, e.g. 4kiB.  Also, `read` and `write` are system-call names.  Did you mean system calls?  Or did you mean a CPU instruction called `read`?  Instruction names always use load/store (or move), not read/write.  e.g. ARM `ldr r0, [r1]` uses r1 as a pointer and loads a word from the pointed-to memory into r0.  (Cache hit/miss details and hardware prefetching are all invisible to software, handled by hardware.  You can only measure by timing or with perf counters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So if the data stored in L2 cache, does the OS copy this page to L1 cache immediately ?

Typically yes. This allows the L1 cache to do its job later if the data is required.

> Now, if we want to write data, it is immediately write to L1 or L2 cache ?

To the L1 cache. Typically it will then be marked modified in the L1 cache and invalid in the L2 cache so that the caching hardware knows where the most current value is located.

Note that these are how things are usually done. There are all kinds of crazy variations out there.

Comment: Just to be careful with wording, the hardware does this, not the OS.

Answer (score 2):

> So if the data stored in L2 cache, does the OS copy this page to L1 cache immediately ?

NO. The operating system does not move data among the caches.

There are very few processors where the operating system has any control over the contents of caches.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this point. I wish processors allowed the OS more control over the upper-level caches. This would be very cool for building performance-oriented applications and operating systems.